# Some photos do not load with on Android with Chrome

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, lazy-loading

I have made a website with Bootstrap, works great on all PC major browsers but some photos do not load on mobile devices. Most images that do not load are in modals. I am using Lazy Load to load some photos but not the UI images. For the UI images I use retina.js.

I have tested with Android Chrome and with Slepnir (is using the Chromium engine). Any idea how can I fix this?

The address is: www.o-p-a-l.eu

EDIT: the test address is test.o-p-a-l.eu

EDIT 2: I have tested on the Android default browser as well, the same problem.

EDIT 3: Any js script that checks if the images are loaded and reload the ones that are not? I am using the network internet but is fast. On Wi-Fi is the same problem.

Comment: Please enter a full link for the address.

Comment: http://test.o-p-a-l.eu and http://www.o-p-a-l.eu are working.

Comment: Oh, Stack Overflow removes the www